# Multiple liveCDs on one USB

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

Is there an easy way to install multiple liveCDs ont a USB drive? Specifically kubuntu and arch. I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to do this since both distros include their own boot loader when installed the way they suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665/installing-grub-2-on-a-usb-flash-drive

Comment: @phunehehe: not really a duplicate because the question is not grub specific

Comment: I was somewhat confused, but after a while thinking I agree that although requiring the same answer, the question is different. Is there somewhere a guideline to this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide to do exactly this on this question:

[Installing Grub 2 on a USB flash drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665/installing-grub-2-on-a-usb-flash-drive)

as the first answer. It answers it perfectly (assuming that I know what you are asking) and allows you to have multiple isos on a usb stick, by installing grub.

Answer (score 0):

*"YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. Contrary to MultiBootISO's which used grub to boot ISO files directly from USB, YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary."*

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/