# How to install Fedora from an ISO on a USB?

Tags: fedora, debian, usb

I have a Fedora 14 x86_64 iso image and I want to install it using a USB stick. How do I get this stick to boot up, and use the image to start the installation? I'm running Debian.

Comment: Do you want to install for real, or do you want a USB running Fedora with persistance storage?

Comment: I want to install Fedora on a VM, but I think that's irrelevant.

Comment: On a VM is easier you do not need a usb.  Most VM software allows install directly from iso.  YOu can create a virtual dvd-rom, mount iso to it and mount rom on boot of your new VM, the rest is installing.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665/250

Comment: There's a very lengthy tutorial here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo#How_to_Make_a_bootable_USB_Drive_to_Install_Fedora_instead_of_using_a_physical_DVD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora has a good page about this here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo . They have a tool called [live usb creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/) that will setup the USB for you.

For a general tool, [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to create a bootable USB drive from just about any bootable ISO image.

Comment: live usb creator was buggy for me using a x64 desktop to build a x86 xbmc build, usually I use a windows desktop with usb creator as it seems to be less problematic than linux versions of it.  good answer regardless!

Comment: can *live usb creator* use normal ISO's (not Live ones)?

Comment: I would expect Live USB Creator to be able use any bootable ISO, but I don't know for sure. UNetbootin definitely will.

Comment: UNetbootin has never worked for any of my distros. Neither has the Fedora tool.

Comment: um. UNetbootin is for live USB creation only, not for what OP wants. You can create live USB, but you won't be able to install from it.

Comment: @Andre That is incorrect. If the ISO you use to make the bootable USB with is an installation image, you can install from it.