# Creating bootable usb stick with NetBSD installer on Linux

Tags: usb, netbsd

How can I create bootable usb stick with NetBSD installer on Linux?

I tried to use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), but on download list there is only 4.0 version and when I select my ISO with 5.1 version it doesn't work (it create only few config files) . Other instruction that I found was NetBSD specific and I don't have NetBSD installed...

Comment: I asked a question about booting about install Grub on a USB stick. Since Grub can boot FreeBSD you can give that a try. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665/250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to create anything: NetBSD now provides the Installer on ready to use USB images.
you can download them here:
ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub//NetBSD/NetBSD-5.1/memstick/

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ubuntu installed, try

```
System -> Administration -> Startup Disk Creator
```

Select your ISO and the USB drive, push the button... done!

Comment: Startup disk creator works only with Ubuntu and its derivatives. I've tried it.

Comment: I used this before with non-Ubuntu images (even non-debian based ones). But yes, they were all Linux systems using grub bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iso prepared to be an usb stick like this one:
https://cdn.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-7.1/images/NetBSD-7.1-amd64-install.img.gz

Just download it and then use dd

if you don't know how to use dd login as root and do that:

```
dd if=/home/user/Downloads/NetBSD-7.1-amd64-install.img.gz of=/dev/sdb
```

Note if means input file, so it needs a path, just put the path to locate the netbsd iso like i did. of means output file it needs a path to find the usb

You can use gparted or something like that {including dmesg} to find what name has your usb stick, in the example i did it means /dev/sdb, but sure your usb has a different one so look about.

PD be careful with dd, you can destroy data. Remember if it's input file and of output, so whatever device you put in of=/dev/device will be erased and writed

Comment: should not `gunzip *.img.gz` be done first, and then `dd `if=*.img` - to dump the raw usb image?