# Iso booting with grub2

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, iso

I am using Linux Mint 10, and it is installed on `sda8`.

I edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Adding 40_custom.">&2
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "fedora ISO" {
    loopback loop (hd0,8)/boot/iso/Fedora-14-i386-DVD.iso
    linux  (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz boot=isolinux iso-scan/filename=/boot/iso/Fedora$
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

Then I ran `sudo update-grub2`. After rebooting, I chose “Fedora ISO”. The computer restarted.

I tried following [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847), but it didn't work.

Do I need to change the file permissions of the `boot` and `casper` folders 
or there is some other problem?

Comment: Related: [Installing Grub (2) on a USB flash drive](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665/250)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the lines point to correct file locations. For example, I have a Fedora ISO with me, but I cannot find the file `/boot/vmlinuz` or `/boot/initrd.img` in it. At the very least you should have:

```
menuentry "Fedora ISO" {
    loopback loop (hd0,8)/path/to/Fedora-14-i386-DVD.iso
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz0 boot=isolinux iso-scan/filename=/Fedora13.iso splash --
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd0.img
}
```

Maybe you misunderstood that, but `linux` and `initrd` above point to the entries inside the ISO, not on your hard drive.

Comment: phunehehe,i have changed the code as u said still when i choose fedora Iso at grub,the pc restarts

Comment: Can you help me at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249049/66803 ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried Grub2 to boot directly to a .iso`` file with Fedora, CentOS live CD but failed. I think it is because they are using the CD's label to detect the root device. I have extracted Fedora's ISO content to a folder and hook it with this:

```
menuentry "Fedora 16 [GNOME] (x86_64)" --class fedora --class os {
  linux /boot/iso/Fedora-16-x86_64-Live-GNOME/isolinux/vmlinuz0 root=UUID=DB92-7E14 rootfstype=vfat ro liveimg quiet  rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0
  initrd /boot/iso/Fedora-16-x86_64-Live-GNOME/isolinux/initrd0.img
}
```

You can find your boot partition UUID by using this command line:

```
ls -lh /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Remember to change your boot partition type to your.