# Installing Ubuntu 15.04 through Mint 17.1

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation

I am currently using Mint 17.1 on a machine having both legacy BIOS and UEFI. Secure Boot is off. **Mint is running on a fully encrypted physical partition and with swap partition is encrypted too.** There is a 2 GB unencrypted /boot partition.

I wanted to know if there's a way I can install Ubuntu without creating a bootable CD or USB disk. Earlier in windows there was a way to download and install Ubuntu from windows interface. Can same be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for I believe you are looking for [Iso booting with grub2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/iso-booting-with-grub2) or the equivalent for your bootloader. Gummiboot seems to support it as well for instance. Be warned however that the partition on which the iso is placed has to be wisely chosen, since you may not be able to use that same partition in your new installation. [The ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) provides some insight about that.