# Is there any way to boot from iso while running system from live disk?

Tags: grub2, iso, livecd, bootable

This is bit complicated question let me explain what is expected:

I know that we can add GRUB `menuentry` with location of ISO file and boot from ISO using GRUB entry. (i.e [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/340171/256099) method)

But suppose that:

- I've ISO file of a GNU/Linux (say Trisquel 7.0) stored in computer (hard-disk) say at `/dev/sda3/`
- I want to install it on `/dev/sda4`
- I've Ubuntu 14.04 installation (bootable) disk from which I can install or try the live system.
- Consider I've no operating system installed currently or installed system is crashed/corrupted (nothing to do with current boot-loader)

The question is: With the Installation disk, running live environment (say try without installing of Ubuntu 14.04), Can I boot from the ISO (of Trisquel 7.0) from `/dev/sda3` and install that system on `/dev/sda4`? How do I?

<sup>Note:I agree that it is better to create/burn live disk/USB of the system I want to install from iso but If there is no disk/usb available right now then Can I do such operation mentioned in question?</sup>

I think there is one possible technique: Install GRUB from (Ubuntu's) live environment on HDD pointing the path of ISO (Trisquel) that I finally want to boot from! How to?

Comment: I would suggest, mount /dev/sda3 on /mnt, cd /mnt/boot, find install lines in grub/menu.lst, `kexec /vmlunix... install`. you might need some try ...

Answer (score 2):

Tested on VM. Was able to boot from Trisquel Live ISO (residing on hard disk) using this method.

Required steps would look like this:

1. After booting to your Ubuntu Live disk, start it's installation process. You would need to do at least minimal installation of the system on `/dev/sda4` to get a working and bootable GRUB. But it's easier to just do full installation (it's rather quick).

   1.a. Be sure to restrict the installation to change only the contents of `/dev/sda4`. To do so you would need to select "Something else" when asked about hard disk settings.
2. Test that your fresh GRUB is working by booting to the installed system.

   2.a. **Note:** Under Ubuntu to show GRUB menu press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on system start. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/a/16049) contains instructions on how to enable showing of GRUB menu on every boot.
3. Now you need to add the required menuentry as explained in [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/340171/256099) that you mentioned. Providing adaptation:

   3.a. I assume, that the Trisquel ISO is located at root of `/dev/sda3/`.

   The menuentry for the ISO image needs to be added to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Edit the file by:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
   ```

   And replace the text in that file with this one:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec tail -n +3 $0
   # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
   # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
   # the 'exec tail' line above.

   menuentry "Trisquel ISO" {
           set isofile="/trisquel_7.0_amd64.iso"
           loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile
           linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
           initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
   }
   ```

   Where is:

   - `Trisquel ISO` = The name you want to display in the Grub menu.
   - `/trisquel_7.0_amd64.iso` = The path to the ISO image on target partition.
   - `(hd0,3)` = The partition which contains the ISO image (for GRUB it's equal to `/dev/sda3` from linux: "sda1" == "(hd0,1)"; "sdb2" == "(hd1,2)"; ...).
   - note: the `tail -n +3` means simply "which line grub starts to read the configuration from as is". the 3th line in this example is the first comment line, which is fine.

   3.b. Save and close this file and now run this command (to apply changes):

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Now you should be able to boot from ISO on hard disk.
   **Note:** if you require using `/dev/sda3` in installation process, then use this command from the Live CD environment:

   ```
   sudo umount -l /isodevice
   ```

Futher reading: [reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) and [examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples) of Ubuntu menuentries.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this on a kickstart-base distro, but it should work as well for others.
mount the iso, pull out files:
cat .....isolinux/initrd.img | unxz | cpio -idm
modify the kickstart file and store in new file

Now the tricky part... take the iso and shove it into a new initrd tree (copied from the original initrd.img), then use dracut to put a script in that will create a device file for it with 'losetup' in the early boot.  Then use boot param inst.repo=hd:/dev/loop9 (your loop) and use inst.ks=file:////  (the kickstart file.. potentially pulled from the iso if there was one).

Then use kexec -l to load the new initramfs and kernel and rebooting will cause the iso to be loaded/started.

I'm mainly placing this answer here to confirm that a) it can be done, and b) my experience has been that it's pretty complex.